# In DUNS number lookup its shows organisation list but that's not my

Tags: ios, apple-developer-account

I am new to swift and I am trying to register my organisation to apple store for that I need DUNS number. But it shows some organisation in list but that's not my and it is not giving
me any option to register new one. Did somebody face this problem. Please help me. Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: @Paulw11 It is redirecting me to https://developer.apple.com/support/D-U-N-S/ this page after lookup there is no option to get new DUNS number.There is list of organisation But those are not my

Comment: You will need to contact Dunn and Bradstreet for assistance https://support.dnb.com/?CUST=APPLEDEV